# How to sort a listview/Gridview control of data of current view instead of entire data?

Tags: asp.net, listview, sorting, gridview, datagrid

I have binded the 100 records on Listview control with page size as 5. If i click column header, the entire 100 records should be sorted and if i clicked on image next to column header, it should sort the current view of 5 records. Can anyone tell me how to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you put Listview/gridview/datagrid as a tag.  This makes me think you are only using the listview for display?  Are you using the existing update/delete/insert functionality of a listview?

If not there is definately better ways to go about this.

If you are tied to a Listview control, this type of functionality is not built in to ListView.  You can certainly sort all 100 with built in ListView functionality, however a the sub sort  isn't.

I have not tried to do exactly what you are asking to do but I would approach the problem by building new functionality using the ListView.  You should be able to write a custom pager and handle the paging and sorting on your own.  This way you can handle the paging and sorting however you want.  Perhaps something as simple as only bind enough records for 1 page and the image can handle normal Listview sorting and when they click the column header, find the data that needs to be displayed and sort it then find which "page" of data to rebind to the grid.